# transform an adjacency list into a sparse adjacency matrix using python

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, data-manipulation

When using scipy, I was able to transform my data in the following format:

```
(row, col)  (weight)
(0, 0)      5
(0, 47)     5
(0, 144)    5
(0, 253)    4
(0, 513)    5
...
(6039, 3107)    5
(6039, 3115)    3
(6039, 3130)    4
(6039, 3132)    2
```

How can I transform this into an array or sparse matrix with zeros for missing weight values as such? (based on the data above, column 1 to 46 should be filled with zeros, and so on...)

```
0 1 2 3  ... 47 48 49 50
1 [0 0 0 0 ... 5 0 0 0 0
2  2 0 1 0 ... 4 0 5 0 0
3  3 1 0 5 ... 1 0 0 4 2
4  0 0 0 4 ... 5 0 1 3 0
5  5 1 5 4 ... 0 0 3 0 1]
```

I know it is better in terms of memory to keep the data in the format above, but I need it as a matrix for experimentation.

Comment: What have you tried? This is pretty trivial to do. Also, depending on how big your dataset is, it may not be feasible to load all of it in to memory at once. Show some code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`scipy.sparse` does it for you.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import dok_matrix

your_data = [((2, 7), 1)]

XDIM, YDIM = 10, 10 # Replace with your values

dct = {}
for (row, col), weight in your_data:
    dct[(row, col)] = weight

smat = dok_matrix((XDIM, YDIM))
smat.update(dct)

dense = smat.toarray()

print dense

'''
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
'''
```

Comment: I'm using Python3.6 and scipy 1.0.0 and this exact code produces `NotImplementedError: Direct modification to dok_matrix element is not allowed.` - Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: Seems to be a change in scipy. Using pandas you can do `pd.Series(dct).unstack().values` where `dct` is a dictionary with tuples as keys and weights as values.

Comment: @BéatriceMoissinac Or `smat._update(dct)`, see [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/8338).